# jQuery Trigger - returning only a single object and not all objects fetched by JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

so I am learning jQuery and I have created a trigger event executed when JSON data is retrieved. I want all the objects to be fetched but am unable to do so. I think it is due to how the JSON object is retrieved.

Here is a code that I am using.

```
<script>

$.getJSON('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', function( results ){
    console.log(results) // prints the correct value. All the objects
    $(document).trigger('jph/photos', results);
}); 

$(document).on('jph/photos', function(e, results ){
    console.log( results ) // returns a single object??
    $('ul.tweets').html(
        $.map(results, function(obj, index){
            return '<li>'+obj.name+'</li>';
        })
    );  
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the extra params value is flattened if it is an array meaning if you pass an array as the second parameter then each object in the array is passed as a separate parameter to the callback.

ie, if you pass an array with 3 items, the the callback will receive 4 params in total like `function(event, item1, item2, item3){}` instead of `function(event, arrayof3items){}`.

One solution to this is to wrap your array with another array so that when the wrapping array is flattened it will get the original array and that will be passed as the argument to the callback like

```
$.getJSON('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', function (results) {
    console.log(results) // prints the correct value. All the objects
    $(document).trigger('jph/photos', [results]);
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by flattened?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting parameter to `.trigger` as array of objects, utilizing `Array.prototype.slice` at event handler

```js
var data = [{
  "name": 123
}, {
  "name": 456
}];

$(document).on("jph/photos", function(e) {
  // slice arguments starting at index 1
  var results = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  $("ul.tweets").html(
    $.map(results, function(obj, index) {
      return '<li>' + obj.name + '</li>';
    })
  );
});

$(document).trigger("jph/photos", data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul class="tweets"></ul>
```

Comment: I am not sure why is this happening, I tried another json data and it worked fine and with some I am facing this problem.

Comment: Not certain interpret  _"I am not sure why is this happening, I tried another json data and it worked fine and with some I am facing this problem."_ correctly ? Is Question resolved ?

Comment: yes, it did as a matter of fact both the answers worked. I am a little confused though, in some cases I don't need to use prototype and I get all the objects but in these cases I have to use prototype. I am not sure why is this happening.